# varnish nginx proxy protocol

Tags: nginx, varnish, proxy-protocol

I have this install from this guide https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/varnish/use-varnish-and-nginx-to-serve-wordpress-over-ssl-and-http-on-debian-8

is there any advantage for using proxoy protocol? from 
https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/five-steps-to-secure-varnish-with-hitch-and-lets-encrypt

to this setup (I have varnish 5)

if so, what is the modification needed for the setup in the linode link above?

best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, it will not be possible to use PROXY protocol in the linked setup.

Nginx supports PROXY protocol only on the client side (i.e. when there is another proxy forwarding requests to it). It doesn't support PROXY protocol with `proxy_pass`, where it would make more sense for Varnish + Nginx SSL setup. Sorry about that.

Comment: do I have to use port 80 in varnish backend port?, when I did that; website like isvarnishworking.com was not able to read the varnish header unless it is on port 80

Comment: looks like it directly connects with port 80, anyway other ports shows cache hits